# Use Android Phone as HID keyboard for Mac mini

Tags: mac, keyboard, bluetooth, android

I am currently not at home and brought my Mac mini with me in the belief I could enable Remote Desktop access to control it over my MacBook because I don't have a keyboard or mouse with me.

I forgot to enable it eventually and now I am struggling to log into it to enable Remote Access, I already tried it with several apps on my Samsung Galaxy A41 that emulates a Bluetooth keyboard without the need of installing a software on the client but my Mac mini won't recognize the phone as a keyboard on the login screen. Is there an option to get access to my Mac with my Android phone or MacBook?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. sorry for my bad English, I am from Germany